# How to drop/remove outliers from Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have a code written to take an average of multiple images to retrieve the background, which basically removes the moving objects in the images. I've been trying to drop outliers before averaging so that I just get the background rather than getting the faded objects too. I've tried a few tricks, with the most recent one being this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import stats

# Load images
im0 = np.array(Image.open('test1/1.jpg'))
im1 = np.array(Image.open('test1/2.jpg'))
im2 = np.array(Image.open('test1/3.jpg'))

# Stack the 3 images into a 4d sequence
sequence = np.stack((im0, im1, im2), axis=3)

mean = np.mean(sequence, axis=3)
sd = np.std(sequence, axis=3)

finalSequence = [x for x in sequence if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]
finalSequence = [x for x in finalSequence if (x < mean + 2 * sd)]

# Repace each pixel by mean of the sequence
result = np.mean(finalSequence, axis=3).astype(np.uint8)

# Save to disk
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

This gives me an error:

```
final_list = [x for x in sequence if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (474,3,3) (266,474,3)
```

Any help or a workaround to doing this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest taking the median rather than the mean.  That should handle most outliers.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without having the packages installed. 
Your operation does not work because the arrays have different shapes [numpy shapes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).
You can view them with:

```
print(x.shape)
print(mean.shape)
print(sd.shape)
```

You can also multiply the mean/sd with np.ones(sequence.shape)
and then compare the entire arrays instead of looping through them
(should be more efficient)

```
mean_vec = mean * np.ones(sequence.shape)
sd_vec = sd * np.ones(sequence.shape)
sequence > (mean_vec - 2 * sd_vec)
```